# Floor function of powers of $2$

Tags: arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there any way to know the exact value of

$$\left(\left\lfloor 2^{\frac{n}{2}} \right\rfloor\right)^2$$

for $n$ an integer $n>0$?

When $n$ is even, the solution is trivial, since we do not have to face any fractional part. On the other hand, for $n$ an odd number, it seems difficult to get the exact value.

We could try to get an aporoximation, but using $\lfloor x \rfloor = x + O(1)$ gives a pretty inaccurate result.

Any idea?

Edit: Would it be possible to get it if we knew the value of $$\left(\left\lfloor 2^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \right\rfloor\right)^2$$

? (A recursive fomula)

Comment: This is just the greatest perfect square less than or equal to $2^n$. For instance, $3\to4$, $5\to25$, $6\to64$. There's not really a closed form for it other than what you have written.

Comment: This is sequence $A065732$ in $OEIS$. Nothing more than what Grant B. Commented.

Comment: The main idea behind my "Edit" was trying to establish a recursive formula

Comment: If it were possible to obtain a closed form expression for all $n$, then, by restricting to odd values $n$, we could obtain a closed form expression for the values of OEIS [A084188](https://oeis.org/A084188) - This would mean that we could derive a closed expression for the $n^{th}$ digit in the binary representation of $\sqrt{2}$, which I don't think is possible given that it is irrational.

Comment: @PaulAljabar.Maybe this helps:http://community.wolfram.com/web/community/groups/-/m/t/1063480

Comment: That seems interesting. Maybe, we now have the recipe and the ingredients. The problem would be joining both things

Comment: On the other hand, if you try to work with that fornula involving logs you will eventually get stuck at an expression of the form $\arctan (\tan(f(n))$ or something similar, which returns you to the original floor function

Comment: I've found out, since writing the above, that algebraic numbers are indeed [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number#Properties). As $\sqrt{2}$ is algebraic, it must be computable (at least algorithmically).

Comment: Thanks [Mariusz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276773/mariusz-iwaniuk), very interesting. How does one go about proving the convergence of the series expansion of $\log(1-z)$ for $|z| = 1$, which seems to be relied on in the expression?

Comment: @PaulAljabar.I'm engineer and math hobbyst,but  proving the convergence,well: You have to ask this question to https://math.stackexchange.com maybe someone smarter will answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using identity:
$$\lfloor x\rfloor =x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin (2 k \pi  x)}{k}}{\pi }$$

Solve sum ,substitute `x=2^(n/2)` and raise to the power 2 we have:

$$\left\lfloor 2^{n/2}\right\rfloor ^2=\frac{\left(\left(-1+2^{1+\frac{n}{2}}\right) \pi -i \log \left(1-e^{-i
   2^{1+\frac{n}{2}} \pi }\right)+i \log \left(1-e^{i 2^{1+\frac{n}{2}} \pi }\right)\right)^2}{4 \pi ^2} = 1/4\,{\frac { \left( {2}^{1+n/2}\pi-2\,{\rm arccot} \left(\cot \left( 
\pi\,{2}^{n/2} \right) \right) \right) ^{2}}{{\pi}^{2}}}
$$
and:
$$\left\lfloor 2^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\right\rfloor ^2=\frac{\left(\left(-1+2^{n/2}\right) \pi -i \log \left(1-e^{-i 2^{n/2}
   \pi }\right)+i \log \left(1-e^{i 2^{n/2} \pi }\right)\right)^2}{4 \pi ^2} = 1/4\,{\frac {1}{{\pi}^{2}} \left( \pi\,{2}^{n/2}-\pi-2\,\arctan
 \left( {\frac {\sin \left( \pi\,{2}^{n/2} \right) }{-1+\cos \left( 
\pi\,{2}^{n/2} \right) }} \right)  \right) ^{2}}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your great answer (+1), but I think I will wait a bit to see if any other idea arises before checking this post as solved